# My problem in the definition of Dirichlet generating function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, riemann-zeta, mobius-function

> In the  [definition of Dirichlet generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer)  "for the square-free numbers " is: $$ \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {|\mu(n)|}{n^s}   $$
>
> where $\mu$ is Moebius function .

Now suppose that: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {|\mu(n)|}{n^s} =0  $$

then it is possible for  $\mu(n)=0$ this implies $n$ is not a square free

and in the same time $\zeta(s)=0 $ according to the identity above .

My question here : How the definition of Dirichlet generating function Given

for square free number $n$ and in the same time  no exception in the above

identity  if  RH were true ?

Thank you for any help

Comment: I don't understand your concern. For which $n$ do you conclude that $n$ is square-free? BTW, in the domain where the Dirchlet series converges ($\Re s>1$) none of the functions mentioned has a zero

Comment: yes , n is a square free , pleas look if RH is true then n will not a square free and the definition given for  square -free number

Comment: and if i accept what you said to me about Re(s)>1 , why (Re(s)>1) it's not montioned in the above identity or definition of GF

Comment: Why they left out an important condition is something you may want to ask on the talk page of that WP article

Comment: yes , and Re(s)>1 is important conditions for me .if it's not montioned then n should become not square -free

Comment: You are also aware that the sum is principally over all $n$, square-free and non-square-free alike? It's just that we can drop the non-square-free ones right away because $\mu(n)=0$ for them

Comment: no, it's stated  that the  sum is principally over all n which are square-free (pleas look the definition in wikipedia)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, i edited it in wikipedia and i think it were selected ,you can check this link again :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer

Answer (score 2):

The identity:

$$ \text{Re}(s)>1,\qquad \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu^2(n)}{n^s} $$
follows from [Euler's product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product). Obviously $\mu^2(n)$ is a multiplicative function $\in\{0,1\}$, hence for any $s$ such that $\text{Re}(s)>1$ we have:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu^2(n)}{n^s}=\prod_{p}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}=\frac{\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}}{\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{2s}}\right)^{-1}}=\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}.$$
Euler's product also gives that $\zeta(s)$ cannot vanish on $\text{Re}(s)>1$.

Comment: Thank you, then the missed important condition in the above definition  is :Re(s)>1